# Make a button that advances dates by a week in excel

Tags: excel, date

In Excel I have a date field.
I would like to make a button that when pressed will add one week to the date in that date field. I have only made one other macro button before so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to vote to close, at least have the courtesy to comment and explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code hould do the trick:

```
Sub advanceDatebyOneWeek()

   Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date
   firstDate = DateValue(Range("D5").Value)
   secondDate = DateAdd("d", 7, firstDate)
   Range("D5").Value = secondDate

End Sub
```

Where:

1. D5 is the cell containing the date
2. 7 is the number of days to add to the date.

References:
http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-programming-date-time-excel-vba.html

regards
Arcass

Comment: Sounds like that is what I'm looking for. I'll try it tomorrow and if it does mark as correct.